# Netbeans issue: No new lines with PHP

Tags: php, netbeans

I've started learning PHP and I've been using the Netbeans IDE.

I've been having an issue with Netbeans when I try to echo exact multiline text, as it is just coming out on one line.

I've tried \n, \r, and <<<_END ... _END; but the text still comes out on one line so I think it's an issue with Netbeans itself. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this has something to do with your editor. Where do you view your output? In a browser? try "<br>" instead

Comment: Not sure whether `HEREDOC` supports newline characters. Test using `"\n"`, has to be double quote otherwise `PHP` won't actually send a \n character. -- According to DOCS, HEREDOC should support the newline character.

Comment: I'm using a localhost (zend) on chrome. Using <br> sort of worked, it did take a new line but one of the lines is about 5 lines below the rest now.

Comment: I also tried \n in single and double quotes but neither worked. Heredoc just didn't work at all for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your editor. If you view the output in a browser, it is correct that no line break will be visible by using `\n` or `\r\n`. The browser renders HTML and so you only see a new line if you echo a `<br>` (the HTML tag for linebreak). However If you view the source of your generated HTML in your browser you should see a line break for `\r\n`.

Another way to display `\r\n` line breaks in your browser is to use `<pre></pre>`. E.g.

```
echo "<pre>";
echo "line 1 \r\n";
echo "line 2 \r\n";
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using a book to learn php and I was getting really confused by this, read your comment and then skipped ahead a few pages, and it says the same basically, that HTML rules takeover in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.   `/n`  was not working in NetBeans.

add  below code   after `< ? php`

`header("Content-type:text/plain");`

it solves   `/n`   new line problem in NetBeans or etc.